# How to check if a digital signature token has signing and encryption

Tags: certificate, token, digital-signature

I have a dsc token, im aware that they can be only signing, or they can be signing and encryption. How do i check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KeyUsageFlag for X509 certificate is a bitwise flag.

Please refer: [X509KeyUsageFlags Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509keyusageflags?view=net-5.0)

There can be a single certificate with both the flag set (addation of values for DigitalSignature and KeyEncipherment) i.e. 128 + 32 or two different certificates. This depends on how Certifying Authority choses to issue the certificate.

> How do i check?

**Method 1:** You must have Smartcard or USB Token driver installed which pushesh Certificates in token to Windows Certificate Store on inserting the token. Then run certmgr.msc to open Certificate Manager; go to Personal Certificates, double click the required certificate to open the Certificate Details and check Key Usage property in Details tab.  Values displayed here are in Hex. like: Digital Signature (80)

**Method 2:**
You may filter on key values and check as above.

Install Signer.Digital Browser Extension as described [here](https://web.signer.digital/GetStarted)

Once Extension is installed and available in the browser, open any site so that browser loads extension script and execute below commands from the console of the browser

SignerDigital.getSelectedCertificate("", 32) - to list only Encryption Certificates
SignerDigital.getSelectedCertificate("", 128) - to list only DigitalSignature Certificates.

Here 32 and 128 are X509KeyUsageFilter values as discussed above.